# Rails is generating completely blank model files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been tinkering around with a Rails project (actually, trying to get it to pick up view templates from lib/templates, which was successful). Now, however, if I generate a scaffold, I get the view files, the migration, but NOT the model file - it creates a zero length file in app/models, but gives it no content.

What on earth have I done?

The way in which I got the thing to pick up the templates was to add a

```
config.generators do |g|
```

block, but even if I comment that out now, I can't get rails g model ... to create a model file.

Any clues? FWIW, if I go into an existing alternative rails project, I can create model files perfectly - it's something to do with this project. And I'd quite like to find out what it is rather than blowing the project away and starting again...